# What are these green weeds on my grass?

Tags: identification, lawn, grass, weed-control, seeds

One month ago I used weed killer and waited two weeks to overseed and after seeing all weeds dead I overseed and used starter fertilizer and now I have some green weeds on my grass. What are they? what did I do wrong? Right side have no problems. I haven't seen new grass anywhere though, maybe they dried because of sun. Before overseed I did rake my grass and got rid of dead grass.  I kept soil moist all the time. Temp. was around 70-80 range. Kansas City, Missouri.

I don't know the last time it was fertilized.

**Before**

[image]

[image]

**After**

[image]
[![][4]][4]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Regular mowing at lower level should solve the problem (possibly without watering after the mowing).

Comment: I mow twice a week with a high level and yes I do water after mowing :) Maybe these two causing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like either crabgrass or quackgrass.

What overseed mix did you use? It seems likely this is a seed from that mix.

Comment: I used ScottsTurf Builder Grass Seed Sun and Shade Mix. I haven't seen any new grass growing and these weeds only grow only one side but seed two sides.
https://www.scotts.com/en-us/products/grass-seed/scotts-turf-builder-grass-seed-sun-shade-mix